# SharePoint 2013 Documents webpart displaying all files from specific Document Library

Tags: web-parts, sharepoint-2013

I’ve created new Site Collection inside of my PWA, named: Test Site Collection (url: XXX/sites/test-site-collection/).

Later, I’ve added new Document Library from Site Contents of this Site Collection, named Sample Docs (XXX/sites/test-site-collection/Sample%20docs/Forms/AllItems.aspx).

The thing is, I do not know how should I display the whole content of this Sample Docs Document Library in the new Documents web part (Edit Page -> Add a Web Part -> Categories: Apps -> Parts: Documents) on the Test Site Collection default home page.

Could you please let me know how should I achieve this? I’d like to have 1:1 mapping between the files inside of Sample Docs Document Library and newly created web part.

Not sure if I should create new Search result or something else… Any comments are much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a new Site Collection, since site collections can not (easly) talk with each other (but there are some new APIs for SP developers in SP2013). You should create a new SharePoint SubSite (where did you crated a document library).